# angular 4 with dynamic elements added to form with tabindex

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms

I am using angular 4.

I am trying to add dynamic element to forms.

Here is my code.

First I creat a form using formbuilder.

```
 this.addbookingForm = this.fb.group({
      FROM: ['', Validators.required],
      branch: [''],
      TO:['', Validators.required],
      FROM_NAME: ['', Validators.required],
      FROM_MOBILE: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(9)])],
      TO_NAME: ['', Validators.required],
      TO_MOBILE: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(9)])],
      PAY_TYPE: ['', Validators.required],
      LLR:[''],
      MANUAL_LLR: ['', Validators.required],
      BRANCH_LLR:'',
      DELIVERY_TYPE: ['', Validators.required],
      VIA: ['', Validators.required],
      ST: [true],
      CROSSING: [0],
      ITEMS: this.fb.array([this.initItems()]),
      TOTAL_AMOUNT: [''],
      BOOKING_DATE: [this.currentDate],
      STATUS: ['Booked'],
      FROM_NAME_LABEL : ['']
})

 initItems() {        
    const group = this.fb.group({           
          NAME: [''],
          NO_OF_ITEMS: ['',Validators.required],
          PRICE: [''],
          WEIGHT: [''],
          TOTAL: ['']                     
    });
    return group;
}
```

Here is my html code.

```
<div formArrayName="ITEMS" class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let item of ITEMS.controls; let in=index; let l=last;">                     
    <div class="row" [formGroupName]="in">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="NAME" tabindex="1"  #input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-label">No of Items</label>
            <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$" class="form-control" tabindex="2" formControlName="NO_OF_ITEMS" (change)="onChange(ITEMS.controls[in].value.NO_OF_ITEMS, in)">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-label">Price per Item</label>
            <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$" class="form-control" formControlName="PRICE" tabindex="3" (change)="changePrice(ITEMS.controls[in].value.PRICE,in)">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-label">Weight</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="WEIGHT" tabindex="4">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-label">Total</label>
            <input type="number" pattern="^[0-9]*$" readonly="true" class="form-control" formControlName="TOTAL" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-1" >                                
            <span class="remove-todo ion-ios-close-empty" *ngIf="addbookingForm.controls.ITEMS.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeItems(in, ITEMS.controls[in].value.NO_OF_ITEMS)"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <a (click)="addItems()"  *ngIf="l && show" style="cursor: default" tabindex="5">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>                                                            
        </div>
    </div>
  </diV>
```

Here is addItems().

```
my addItems() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.addbookingForm.controls['ITEMS'];        
        control.push(this.initItems());

  }
```

Each input tag set tab index.First time tabIndex was worked fine.When i click the `addItems()`.Its add dynamic input element to form.

But tabindex not working properly.

I need tabIndex dynamicly when i added elements dynamicly.

Kindly advice me,
Thanks

Comment: You are putting tab index static values, change it to in variable that you are using in ngFor loop, that way it will have different indexes based on how mamy items you have in dinamicaly generated elements

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Can you show any example?